# Win32 Snake game

Tags: c++, windows, snake-game, winapi

I made a trival snake game below to practice my C++ and Win32 programming skills.

```
/* g++ snake.cpp -o snake -lgdi32 -Wl,-subsystem,windows */

#include <deque>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

#include <Windows.h>

#define ID_TIMER 1

constexpr int WND_WIDTH = 500;
constexpr int WND_HEIGHT = 500;

struct Cell
{
    int row, col;
    Cell(int row, int col) : row(row), col(col)
    {}
};

class Snake
{
public:
    Snake(int rows, int cols);
    ~Snake();
    void Update(HWND hWnd);
    void DrawBitmap(HDC hdc, RECT *rect, BITMAPINFO info);
    void HandleKey(WPARAM wParam);
    int GetScore();
private:
    enum Direction { UP = 0, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT };
    enum CellType { EMPTY = 0, SNAKE, FOOD };
    
    std::vector<BYTE> pixels;
    std::deque<Cell> snake;
    
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int dir;
    
    void MakeFood();
    void SetCell(int row, int col, CellType type);
    CellType GetCellType(int row, int col);
    Cell Move(const Cell& cell);
};

Snake::Snake(int rows, int cols)
  : rows(rows), cols(cols)
{
    pixels.resize(rows * cols * 4);
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    Snake::MakeFood();
    snake.push_back(Cell(rows / 2, cols / 2));
    dir = UP;
}

Snake::~Snake()
{}

void Snake::Update(HWND hWnd)
{
    snake.push_back(Snake::Move(snake.back()));
    
    Cell head = snake.back();
    bool eaten = false;
    
    if (Snake::GetCellType(head.row, head.col) == FOOD)
    {
        snake.push_back(Snake::Move(head));
        Cell newHead = snake.back();
        Snake::SetCell(newHead.row, newHead.col, SNAKE);
        eaten = true;
    }
    else if (Snake::GetCellType(head.row, head.col) == SNAKE)
    {
        char buff[200];
        snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "Score: %d", Snake::GetScore());
        KillTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER);
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT(buff), "Game Over!", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    }
    
    Snake::SetCell(head.row, head.col, SNAKE);
    
    Cell tail = snake.front();
    snake.pop_front();
    Snake::SetCell(tail.row, tail.col, EMPTY);
    
    if (eaten) Snake::MakeFood();
}

void Snake::DrawBitmap(HDC hdc, RECT *rect, BITMAPINFO info)
{
    int width = rect->right - rect->left;
    int height = rect->bottom - rect->top;
    
    StretchDIBits(hdc,
                  0,
                  0,
                  width,
                  height,
                  0,
                  0,
                  cols,
                  rows,
                  &pixels[0],
                  &info,
                  DIB_RGB_COLORS,
                  SRCCOPY);
}

void Snake::HandleKey(WPARAM wParam)
{
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case VK_UP:
        dir = UP;
        break;
    case VK_DOWN:
        dir = DOWN;
        break;
    case VK_LEFT:
        dir = LEFT;
        break;
    case VK_RIGHT:
        dir = RIGHT;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int Snake::GetScore()
{
    return snake.size();
}

void Snake::MakeFood()
{
    int row = rand() % rows;
    int col = rand() % cols;
    
    while (Snake::GetCellType(row, col) == SNAKE)
    {
        row = rand() % rows;
        col = rand() % cols;
    }
    
    Snake::SetCell(row, col, FOOD);
}

void Snake::SetCell(int row, int col, CellType type)
{
    int offset = row * cols * 4 + col * 4;
    
    switch (type)
    {
    case EMPTY:
        pixels[offset]     = 0;
        pixels[offset + 1] = 0;
        pixels[offset + 2] = 0;
        pixels[offset + 3] = 255;
        break;
    case SNAKE:
        pixels[offset]     = 0;
        pixels[offset + 1] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 2] = 0;
        pixels[offset + 3] = 255;
        break;
    case FOOD:
        pixels[offset]     = 0;
        pixels[offset + 1] = 0;
        pixels[offset + 2] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 3] = 255;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

Snake::CellType Snake::GetCellType(int row, int col)
{
    int offset = row * rows * 4 + col * 4;
    
    int red = pixels[offset + 2];
    int green = pixels[offset + 1];
    int blue  = pixels[offset];
    
    if (red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 0) return EMPTY;
    if (red == 0 && green == 255 && blue == 0) return SNAKE;
    if (red == 255 && green == 0 && blue == 0) return FOOD;
    
    return EMPTY; // should never reach here
}

Cell Snake::Move(const Cell& cell)
{
    Cell c(cell.row, cell.col);
    
    switch (dir)
    {
    case UP: c.row += 1; break;
    case DOWN: c.row -= 1; break;
    case LEFT: c.col -= 1; break;
    case RIGHT: c.col += 1; break;
    }
    
    // teleportation
    if (c.row == -1)     c.row = rows - 1;
    if (c.row == rows)   c.row = 0;
    if (c.col == -1)     c.col = cols - 1;
    if (c.col == cols)   c.col = 0;
    
    return c;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static BITMAPINFO info;
    static Snake *snake;
    
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        int rows = 40;
        int cols = 40;
        
        info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(info.bmiHeader);
        info.bmiHeader.biWidth = cols;
        info.bmiHeader.biHeight = rows;
        info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
        info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
        info.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        info.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        info.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
        info.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
        
        snake = new Snake(rows, cols);
        
        if(!SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, 80, NULL))
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "Could not set timer!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            PostQuitMessage(1);
        }
        
        break;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        RECT rcClient;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
        snake->DrawBitmap(hdc, &rcClient, info);
        
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        RECT rcClient;
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
        snake->Update(hWnd);
        snake->DrawBitmap(hdc, &rcClient, info);
        
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        break;
    }
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        snake->HandleKey(wParam);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        delete snake;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("MyClass");
    
    WNDCLASS wc;
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;
    
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Window Registration Failed!"), TEXT("Error!"),
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }
    
    hWnd = CreateWindow(szClassName,
                        TEXT("Snake"),
                        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, /* this window style prevents window resizing */
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        WND_WIDTH,
                        WND_HEIGHT,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL);
    
    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Window Creation Failed!"), TEXT("Error!"),
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }
    
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

I'm looking for some ways to improve the quality and efficiency of my C++ code. I'm worried if I'm misusing some data structures. Is Win32 bitmap a good choice for representing a snake game board?

Did I properly structure my code? Is there any way I can improve my code organization?

Miscellaneous feedbacks are welcome!

This is my first time asking for a code review on C++. I hope I get decent feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define ID_TIMER 1`

Just because you're using it with Win32 API calls doesn't change the fact that MACROS==BAD, constexpr==good.

```
struct Cell
{
    int row, col;
    Cell(int row, int col) : row(row), col(col)
    {}
};
```

Your constructor doesn't add anything over what the built-in aggregate initialization would offer, and having it prevents the class from being "trivial".  It's best to leave it out in this case.  You just have to use the C++11 style (curly brace) uniform initialization; e.g.  `snake.push_back(Cell{rows / 2, cols / 2});`.  But actually the class name is not even necessary here, and you can write `snake.push_back({rows / 2, cols / 2});`.

In general, you are not using uniform initialization anywhere.

```
Snake::~Snake()
{}
```

Write, in the class body, `~Snake() = default;` instead.  It is better for a number of reasons.

Your `Snake` class uses the auto-generated copy constructor and assignment operator.  So I wonder why you bothered mentioning the destructor when it doesn't need anything beyond what's automatically supplied, too.  Did you mean for the class to be able to be duplicated and assigned?

```
static Snake *snake;
 ...
 snake = new Snake(rows, cols);
```

Why do you use `new` instead of using a variable of that type?
`rows` and `cols` are declared locally but not `const` or `constexpr`, though they seem like they are constants.

There's nothing in the class that would require its construction to be delayed until
the WM_CREATE message.  Just declare it, with initializer, as a global variable.

---

The raw use of Win32 API functions and types, in an otherwise C++ program, is brutal.  I would always add wrappers and whatnot to improve things.  For example, use RAII/RFID for the various HANDLE types.

---

```
Cell Snake::Move(const Cell& cell)
{
    Cell c(cell.row, cell.col);
    
    switch (dir)
    {
    case UP: c.row += 1; break;
    case DOWN: c.row -= 1; break;
    case LEFT: c.col -= 1; break;
    case RIGHT: c.col += 1; break;
    }
    
    // teleportation
    if (c.row == -1)     c.row = rows - 1;
    if (c.row == rows)   c.row = 0;
    if (c.col == -1)     c.col = cols - 1;
    if (c.col == cols)   c.col = 0;
    
    return c;
}
```

You are passing in a reference to an original cell, but then immediately duplicating it to make a local copy, and then ignoring the one you passed in.
First of all, you're copying it the hard way.  Just write `Cell c = cell;` to invoke the copy constructor.  Second, what is the point of passing by reference (avoid making a copy) just to make a local copy anyway?  You get the same effect, more efficiently, if you just pass by value.

`Cell Snake::Move(Cell c)`

---

```
if (Snake::GetCellType(head.row, head.col) == FOOD)
    {...}
else if (Snake::GetCellType(head.row, head.col) == SNAKE)
```

You're calling to look up the `GetCellType` repeatedly for the same cell!  You already looked it up once, why do so again?

The chained `if` statements should really be a `switch` statement, which will automatically prevent you from repeating the lookup code.

This is in a member function for `Snake`, so why do you need to qualify the calls to `GetCellType` with the same class that you're already in?

---

```
char buff[200];
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "Score: %d", Snake::GetScore());
```

Isn't there a form of `snprintf` that automatically picks up the size of an array when passed as the buffer?  I know a lot of Microsoft's added "buffer overflow safe" functions have this.  It's better to let it pick up the size automatically.

---

```
   int width = rect->right - rect->left;
    int height = rect->bottom - rect->top;
```

In general, use `const` more.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I have a long way to go... What is RAII/RFID?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization  Resource Acquisition Is Initialization / Resource Freeing Is Destruction.  When the HANDLE goes out of scope, it is automatically closed.